# How can I set a password to expire tomorrow in Linux?

Tags: bash, passwords, account

When I create an account for a user, I usually set a default password to be changed asap. I usually set immediate expiry with `passwd -e`. However, when using Hummingbird Exceed, the user gets an ugly popup to change it (trust me, whoever wrote it has no idea what UX is). My idea was to set the expiry to 24 hours, so that they get a regular xterm to do it.

Now, the only thing I could achieve with `passwd` and `chage` is to set the maximum number of days before password expiry, which is not what I want (with `passwd -x1` the user needs to change it everyday). The only working option I figured out is to set the date of the last time the password was changed by calculating `tomorrow - maximum number of days until password expires` with `date -d 'tomorrow - 60 days'` for instance.

Is there any better solution out there?

Comment: See option `-M` of `chage` and [How do I force a user to change the password periodically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105040/how-do-i-force-a-user-to-change-the-password-periodically) and [Linux set default password expiry for all new users](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-set-default-password-expiry-for-all-new-users.html)

Comment: The `-M` option of `chage` is like `passwd -x`. By doing `chage -M1` I will force the user to change the password everyday.